# Angular 7 - Getting Component from imported Module

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular-components, angular-module

### I read all presented questions stack overflow showed me, none of which solved my issue.

I'm new to Angular and I have a couple `Modules` and `Components`. I want a child module to import a component. Then have a parent module import the child module and create it's component. And yes, *I have exported the Component in the child module*.

I want it like so:

- Parent Module

  - Child Module

    - Component (Toy)

But I get the error:

> ERROR in parent/parent.module.ts(8,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ToyComponent'.

**I do not understand why this is not working. I would appreciate an explanation over some sample code. Thanks!**

---

This is the relevant code:

**Toy Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toy',
  templateUrl: './toy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toy.component.css']
})
export class ToyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Toy Component HTML**

```
<p>
  Awesome toy!
</p>
```

---

**Child Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ToyComponent } from './toy/toy.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ToyComponent,
    ChildComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ToyComponent
  ]
})
export class ChildModule { }
```

---

**Parent Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChildModule } from './child/child.module';
import { ParentComponent } from './parent.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ToyComponent,
    ParentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ChildModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
export class ParentModule { }
```

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<p>
  parent works! Child: Toy: <app-toy></app-toy>
</p>
```

Comment: In parent component, you don't need to have ToyComponent in exports and declarations array

Comment: Export was an accident. I have updated the code. Why not in declarations though? I thought I had to declare it in every module I used it. If not, where should I declare the component?

Comment: declarations array contains 'The components, directives, and pipes that belong to this NgModule.' ( according to https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules#ngmodule-metadata ). ToyComponent is a component belongs to ChildModule. It doesn't belong to the parent module. Since, you don't neet to add it as a declarations to parent module

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I do have another question related to this. I hope you could answer: As I cannot declare the `component`, how would I do this with a route. If I have a route to the parent and in the parent I have: `const parentRoutes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: ToyComponent }];`. I get the same error again. `Cannot find name...`. How would I fix this?

Comment: Don't define child module routes in parent route, define routes to child module and implement its own router module in child module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fix:**
 1. Remove `ToyComponent` from the declarations and exports of `ParentModule`.
 2. Declare `ToyComponent` in your `Child Module` and export it.
 3. Add `ChildModule` as an import to your parent module.

**Reason**:
Your `ToyComponent` is declared under your `ChildModule`. Since you use `ToyComponent` in your `ParentModule`, you need to export your `ToyComponent` from your `ChildModule`. And import the `ChildModule` in your `ParentModule`.

Comment: Thanks, I had it exported and imported but had no idea I shouldn't declare it. (For anyone wanting to know why, read Dilan Tharaka comment below the question.)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

It looks like that the import statement for `ToyComponent` is missing in `ParentModule` which causes the error.

**Fix**

- Since `ToyComponent` is added to `exports` in `ChildModule` it must
  not be referenced in `ParentModule`
- Remove `ToyComponent` from the
  `declarations`-list in `ParentModule`

The `ToyComponent` is known to the `ParentModule` because `ChildModule` is added to the `imports`-List.

Comment: Thank you, although your **fix** fixes my issue it is not the answer to my question. Your 'problem' states I didn't have `ToyComponent` imported in the parent. Which is the thing I was trying to avoid.

Comment: No worries, import statement means: `import { ToyComponent } from ...`. It was not related to Angular.

I just tried to explain why you receive the error in the console.
Maybe, I could express it a little bit better.

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I have a question related to that though, if I had a route to the parent, how would I use that because I have to mention the component in the `Routes` array, right?

Comment: Right, a route needs to be configured with path and the corresponding component.
If you want to navigate to this route you either use the Directive `routerLink` (building the href) or you inject Angular's `Router`.

You can either use absolute paths starting with `/` or relative paths accessing parent nodes `../../parent-path`

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer but I don't think I explained it well. What I meant was, I have the `RouterModule` from `@angular/router` imported in my `ParentModule`. I want to redirect it to `ToyComponent` like so: `const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: ToyComponent }];` but I get the same error that ToyComponent is not defined. How would I fix this? Use another `loadChildren` in that array again to the `ChildModule` ?

Comment: In general, you use `loadChildren` referencing the `ChildModule`. The `ChildModule` has it's own `RouterModule` that defines the route for `ToyComponent`.

In this way you do not need to reference ToyComponent in the ParentModule.